# Elasticsearch - Building and Installing plugins

Tags: java, maven, plugins, elasticsearch

I use command `./plugin -i medcl/elasticsearch-analysis-ik/1.2.6` to install plugin
But I got
`Error while installing plugin, reason:IllegalArgumentException: Plugin installation assumed to be site plugin, but contains source code, aborting installation.`
After some searching, somebody says that I should build the plugin source.
But I am not familiar with `JAVA`,[official document](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-plugins.html) do not say this even if `IK Analysis Plugin (by Medcl)` list under `Supported by the community`. How do I build the source code and where to put complied file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has to be build from source as the plugin does not provide a dist(final installable jar) file. The plugin is a maven project. You need not know anything about java. Maven is a dependency management and build tool. So,

**How to build?**

1. Download apache maven - http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi, extract the archive file.
2. Include maven in your system path variable - `C:\<maven path>\maven-3.2.1\bin`
3. Go to the plugin directory root(lets say your root is `c:/es/elasticsearch-analysis-ik`) where there is a `pom.xml` file and execute the command - `mvn compile`
4. This will build the project and generate a jar file in `c:/es/elasticsearch-analysis-ik/target` which is the actual file you need to use in elasticsearch.

**How to use it in elastic search?**
As the file is in you local machine. You can use the below steps to directly install the plugin.

1. Go to elastic search folder.
2. Execute the command - `bin\plugin --url file:////c:/es/elasticsearch-analysis-ik/target/filename.jar --install`

Just restart elasticsearch and tada you have the plugin up and running.

Comment: I think the command "mvn compile" should be "mvn package" for maven 3.0+ to produce filename.jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget to Shutdown elasticsearch and remove previously installed version of plugin:

```
$ES_INSTALL_DIR=PATH_TO_ES_INSTALL
#Shutdown ES
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/nodes/_local/_shutdown'

#Remove old plugin
$ES_INSTALL_DIR/bin/plugin --remove PLUGIN_NAME

#Re-Install plugin
$ES_INSTALL_DIR/bin/plugin --url file:///PATH_TO_PLUGIN --install PLUGIN_NAME

#Start ES
ES_HEAP_SIZE=5026m  $ES_INSTALL_DIR/bin/elasticsearch
```